# What is the best bus route to travel from Salzburg to Munich by public transportation regarding the refugee issue

Tags: public-transport, buses, event-based-effects, munich, salzburg

2 months ago, I booked a hotel in Salzburg and didn't expect the refugee problem.

Can anybody let me know the current status, because I will have a route to take bus from Salzburg to Munich on 6th Oct.

I get updated from news that the trains are stopped between Salzburg and Munich until 4th Oct. So, how should I go to Munich from Salzburg in early Oct?

My question is : Are the buses is still running, what route should I take, and are the potential problems?

Comment: So you've got a bus booked, or a train?

Comment: I didn't book bus or train, because I am not sure the bus still provide service even I booked

Comment: Wait and see how the situation is like on the 6th. It's impossible to predict the situation two weeks from now.  Currently, local trains are operating from right across the border (Freilassing), so one could e.g. use a taxi to get there and then take the train.

Comment: Flights are still operating, but they are now deplaning into the non-Schengen part of the terminal

Comment: @Calchas Flights from Salzburg to Munich?

Comment: [Buses (€7)](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/Salzburg,Salzburg,Austria/Munich,Bavaria,Germany?outbound-date=2015-10-06&trip-type=one-way&adults=1&children=0&seniors=0&child_ages=&senior_ages=&discount_code=) are currently running normally. (I work on busbud.com and we're monitoring on-the-ground updates). You can always check with the bus company at the station Munich for the latest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answer is changeable depending on the exigent circumstances of a current event crisis.

Comment: Dear all. I just take flixbus from salzburg to munich. It takes just 2h 15m. No border check. Just as usual. No refugees as far as i can see

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a problem. Enjoy your train ride.

Refugees flood into Germany
Even with the bottleneck in Hungary, migrants were still making their way to Germany, just not many by train. Germany's government said last month it expected up to 800,000 asylum seekers to come this year -- four times more than in 2014. At Munich's main station, though, the arrival of refugees slowed to a trickle because of the restrictions in Budapest.

Trains between Munich and Salzburg depart from the very early mornings until late evenings essentially on an hourly basis (or even more regularly than that during rush hours). Since both Munich and Salzburg are important transportation hubs, trains pass through the two cities essentially around the clock; however, night-trains might offer inconvenient connections in terms of necessary changes or long driving time.

If you take a train from Salzburg to Munich (or the other way round) at some time between approximately 7 am and 9 pm, you will get there in less than two hours. [Trains between Munich and Salzburg](http://www.visit-salzburg.net/travel/salzburg-to-munich.htm)

Comment: http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/grenzkontrollen-wegen-fluechtlingen-zugverkehr-zwischen-muenchen-und-salzburg-bis-oktober-eingestellt-1.2659534

Comment: No trains between Munich and Salzburg until the 4th of October